# Hide port in Nginx reverse proxy redirection

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

My set up is as follows:

- **Webserver**: app listening on port 8529.
- **Reverse proxy**: Nginx listening on port 80.

The problem is that my Nginx redirects requests to port 8529 and this appears in the URL like so `http://some.domain.com:8529/foo`, which isn't what I want to accomplish.

My current nginx `sites-available` related file is as follows:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name some.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8529/foo;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy   true;
  }

}
```

Where `some.domain.com` is within `/etc/hosts` pointing to `127.0.0.1`.

Any hints?

Comment: Most likely your application is doing this.

Comment: Probably you are right (I tried with a different app and didn't experience this issue). Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Why do you have `proxy_redirect off`?

Comment: Also it's pretty bad idea to have location with trailing slash and proxy_pass without one.

Comment: Just tried different configurations until I got something working. Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: bounty started here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/143735/plesk-how-to-hide-port-in-nginx-forwarding-change-listening-port

Answer (score 7):

Hiding the port during proxying needs these two lines in server body:

```
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

The conf is like:

```
server
{
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
location / {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
access_log off;
}
```

Comment: I've the same problem.
I need it for Plesk.
I added the following:

listen 443 ssl;
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
location / {
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_pass http://localhost:32770;
}
access_log off;

but the port is still appearing

Answer (score 2):

Either your upstream server issued a redirect and you forbid nginx to rewrite it with `proxy_redirect off;` and by missing a trailing slash in `proxy_pass` directive or your application is building these URLs.

Note : as Alexey said, a trailing slash is important in this case as nginx will remove the part of the normalized URI matching the location prefix , i.e. `/` before appending it to the `proxy_pass` URI. So your backend server will receive a request on `/foobar` while your are most likely waiting for `/foo/bar`.