# hide port in ngnix and display site-link instead

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, django

I have already tried suggestions mentioned in:

[Hide port in Nginx reverse proxy redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/627305/hide-port-in-nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection)

but it does not help me.

I have done nginx reverse proxy for my django+gunicorn application and it is open on port 8000. I can access a machine name as http://some_machine:8000 to see my app running. I have mapped localhost running on that machine with machine name using Nginx reverse proxy. I want to hide the port and in url would like something like http://some_machine/zmk instead of http://some_machine:8000/zmk.

I am writing the below content to my `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder:

```
upstream zms {    
  ip_hash;    
  server zms:8000;    
}

# portal

server {    
  location /zmk {    
        proxy_pass http://zms/;    
        # proxy_redirect http://some-machine:8000/ http://some-machine/zmk;    
        port_in_redirect off;    
        # autoindex on;            
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;    
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;    
    }
  listen 8000;    
  server_name localhost    
  server_name_in_redirect off;    
}
```

I am not understanding what am I doing wrong? I have also tried copying the above content to `/etc/nginx/site-available` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `listen` statement to `listen 80` instead. That way your nginx server will listen on port 80 and proxy the traffic to port 8000.

Comment: On port 80 my other ASP.NET app is serving angular static files. If I change it to listen 80, my django app stops working.

Comment: Then put that ASP.NET app also behind your nginx server. How else do you suggest to hide the port number if you can't use port 80?

Comment: ASP.NET is also running behind nginx that is where it is serving static files through port 80

Comment: If they are both behind nginx you can have them both work on port 80....

Comment: Read the documentation. Use two server blocks with different `server_name` statements.