# Directory redirection issue with nginx set as reverse proxy

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have configured the server through Reverse Foloxy as follows:

Nginx reverse proxy(SSL Termination) - Varnish cache - Nginx web server(8080 port)

However, it has the following problems: For example, if you go to https://www.example.com/static (this is an example only, your domain is not my site), you will be redirected to http://www.example.com:8080/static/ . It is the same when accessing not only staic but also other directories. I am wondering how to do something like nginx.conf etc to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Please post the existing configuration of Nginx and Varnish to understand what's going on.

Comment: Nginx -> varnish -> nginx ? Jeez. Pour some gas on and set it on fire. Then add an nginx cache of any sort on the last instance.

Comment: @drookie Nginx on the front end is a reverse proxy that acts as an SSL termination for varnish that doesn't support SSL.

Comment: remove vanish at ALL, nginx do and does the same or better

Comment: Varnish and NGINX are both fantastic software. @anon please share your FRONT SSL terminator nginx config, I suspect you are missing a character or two. Also, do you see expected pages with the extra :8080 ports ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide port in Nginx reverse proxy redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/627305/hide-port-in-nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

Nginx web server (8080 port) It was solved by adding the above setting to the corresponding server block.